# Autolayout for Single UIView and Multiple TableViews

Tags: swift, autolayout

I'm trying to get the following (single) UIView to appear static within the phone screen while either TableView 2 or TableView 3 is being viewed, then horizontally scroll out of view when the user moves to TableView 1.  Essentially, the UIView scrolls in when moving from TableView 1 to TableView 2, remains static from 2 to 3 or 3 to 2, and scrolls away when going back to 1.

[image]

I have the following in my ViewController in an attempt to change the constraints programmatically, however I don't have much experience with this.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if self.scrollView.contentOffset.x <= 400 {
    singleView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: TableView2.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    } else {
        singleView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: TableView2.centerXAnchor, constant: self.scrollView.contentOffset.x).isActive = true
    }
```

It's not working correctly; is there a more appropriate approach I should be taking?  Thanks!

Comment: The stack view was just to keep the 3 tableViews in an easy layout.  I was attempting to programmatically change the constraints to switch with tableView the UIView was attached to.

Comment: Correct; sorry for not explaining well.

Comment: The UIView “attaches” to TableView 2 properly when scrolling from TableView 1; however it doesn’t attach to TableView 3 when scrolled over. I was hoping to just use the constraints offset to place it, but that doesn’t seem to work.

Comment: No; and it's all on one ViewController.  I do have a segmented control that independently sits on top (outside of the scroll view) that controls a sliding animation if the user wants to scroll that way, but that's about it.

Comment: Correct.  I’ll look into that; thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here’s how I would do it.

- Use a paging scroll view.
- Start with the View constrained to the second table view.
- When the user starts to scroll from page 2 to page 3, remove all constraints on the View and constrain it instead to the view controller main view so that it is stationary.
- When the user starts to scroll from page 2 to page 1, reverse that.